# check for numeric input java

Tags: java, validation, input

I need to check a user is inputting a numeric value in java. I've been trying to use the hasNextDouble but am getting weird errors using the hasNextDouble method and am not certain this is the way to perform this check.

Please note I cannot use while loops or any other advanced method except if.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class CentimeterInch
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        final int MAX=100, feet=12, meter=100;
        final double inch=2.54;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("This program converts distances. ");
        System.out.println ("Enter distance and unit (e.g. 37 1 or 100 2):");
        double distance=scan.nextDouble();
        if (!scan.hasNextDouble())
            {
                System.out.println ("please enter a numeric value");
                distance=scan.nextDouble();
            }
        int unitType = scan.nextInt();
        if (distance<0)
            {
                System.out.println ("Please enter a non negative distance");
            }
....
```

I fixed the typo but its still not functioning, when I input for example "a" it crashes. To me it also doesnt make sense to call hasNextDouble after placing the value in the 'double distance' variable but I didn't find any other way yet.
I only have 1 double variable to check, the 'int' does not need validation.

EDIT:
I advance a bit. Now it displays the error before crashing. How do I make it not crash but take the variable again?

```
if(!scan.hasNextDouble())
   System.out.println ("please enter a numeric value");
distance=scan.nextDouble();
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is your "weird errors" ?

Comment: typo: `if (!scan.hasNextDouble())`

Comment: I fixed the typo but its still not functioning, when i input for example 25a it crashes. To me it also doesnt make sense to call hasNextDouble after placing the value in the 'double distance' variable but I didn't find any other way yet. I only have 1 double variable to check.thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `scan.hasNextDouble()` with emphasis on **D**ouble.

Answer (score 0):

Typos aside, you're invoking `hasNextDouble` **after** consuming `nextDouble`.

The easiest way to fetch both in one line is to:

```
if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
    // TODO something
    double foo = scan.nextDouble(); // this consumes the first double
}
else { // TODO exit with error }
if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
    // TODO something else
    double bar = scan.nextDouble(); // this consumes the second double
}
else { // TODO exit with error }
```

If you want it in two gos (i.e. user presses enter twice) you can consume `scan.next()` twice and use `Double.parseDouble` on both `String`, while catching a `NumberFormatException` for format errors.